# how to filter array object using object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an array of object

```
    const devices = [{
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "Pure",
      value: "pure"
    },
    deviceName: "test7"
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    } {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    } {
      label: "ef",
      value: "ef"
    }]
    deviceType: "iPad"
    id: "001"
    connected: false
    enabled: false
  },

  {
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "kandy",
      value: "kandy"
    },
    deviceName: "test4"
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    } {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }]
    deviceType: "iPad"
    id: "004"
    connected: false
    enabled: false
  }
]
```

I want to filter the array by object using `deviceName`,`deviceLocation` and `devicePaymentMethods`

Here is what I have already done and it is working for `deviceName` and `deviceLocation`  but doesn't work for `devicePaymentMethods`

```
const filterByValue = (array, string) => {
return array.filter(o =>
  Object.keys(o).some(k => {
    if (k === "deviceName") {
      return o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
    } else if (k === "deviceLocation") {
      return o[k].label.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
    } else if (k === "devicePaymentMethods") {
       o[k].map(pay => {
          if(pay.label.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase()))
        return pay;
      });
    }
  })
);
};

 filterByValue(devices, "ab")
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: use `filter` instead of `map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to mentioned `return` while filtering the data inside map

```
return o[k].map(pay => {
  if(pay.label.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase()))
    return pay;
```

```js
const devices = [{
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "Pure",
      value: "pure"
    },
    deviceName: "test7",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }, {
      label: "ef",
      value: "ef"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "001",
    connected: false,
    enabled: false,
  },
  {
    deviceLocation: {
      label: "kandy",
      value: "kandy"
    },
    deviceName: "test4",
    devicePaymentMethods: [{
      label: "ab",
      value: "ab"
    }, {
      label: "cd",
      value: "cd"
    }],
    deviceType: "iPad",
    id: "004",
    connected: false,
    enabled: false,
  }
];


const filterByValue = (array, string) => {
  return array.filter(o =>
    Object.keys(o).some(k => {
      if (k === "deviceName") {
        return o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
      } else if (k === "deviceLocation") {
        return o[k].label.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase());
      } else if (k === "devicePaymentMethods") {
        return o[k].some(pay => {
          if (pay.label.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())) {
            return pay;
          }
        });
      }
    })
  );
};

console.log(filterByValue(devices, "ab"));
console.log(filterByValue(devices, "ef"));
```

Comment: filterByValue(devices, "ef") it will return same out put

Comment: Fixed the issue and used `some()` to retrieve one or more values. Hope this helps!  please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slightly different approach with an array of wanted keys and keys for nested array for search.

```js
const
    keys = [['deviceName'], ['deviceLocation', 'label'], ['devicePaymentMethods', 'label']],
    filterByValue = (array, string) => array.filter(object => keys.some(([key, sub]) => {
        if (!(key in object)) return false;
        if (typeof object[key] === 'string' && object[key].toLowerCase() === string) return true;
        if (Array.isArray(object[key]) && sub)
            return object[key].some(o => o[sub].toLowerCase() === string);
    })),
    devices = [{ deviceLocation: { label: "Pure", value: "pure" }, deviceName: "test7", devicePaymentMethods: [{ label: "ab", value: "ab" }, { label: "cd", value: "cd" }, { label: "ef", value: "ef" }], deviceType: "iPad", id: "001", connected: false, enabled: false }, { deviceLocation: { label: "kandy", value: "kandy" }, deviceName: "test4", devicePaymentMethods: [{ label: "ab", value: "ab" }, { label: "cd", value: "cd" }], deviceType: "iPad", id: "004", connected: false, enabled: false }],
    result = filterByValue(devices, "ab");

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```